# How to change the highlight color for a jsdoc-like tag in a C++ file in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

How do I change the highlight color of the Doxygen tokens like `@param` or `@return` so it matches the same visual as JSdoc comments?

What I currently have in my `.cpp/.hpp` files:

[image]

What I would like to see *(this is inside a `.js` file)*:

[image]

For example, is there a way to tell VSCode, all `@params` strings should be blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get JSDoc like comment blocks highlighting using the [Better C++ syntax](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeff-hykin.better-cpp-syntax) package. For more customization checkout this [issue thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4089).

[image]

Comment: So how did you changed @param word color?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  After we determined that your jsdoc comment syntax was not being separately parsed, you found the `Better C++ Syntax` package which does so.  And gives you more control over the contents of a jsdoc comments's internals.  Now this textmate scope will give you the blue colored `@`'s parameters you desired.

---

Try this in your settings.json

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

  "textMateRules": [

    {
      "scope": "storage.type.class.doxygen.cpp",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#00f"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can get the scope by using the `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` command from the command palette.  This allows you to click on a word in your editor, like `@param` and see its textmate scope.  Which then goes into the `tokenColorCustomizations` rule.

There are typically 3 or 4 scopes listed which you can use in a space-separated list if you want more distinction.  Such as if you wanted this rule to apply only to `js` docs:

`"scope": " source.cpp storage.type.class.doxygen.cpp`

Besides the `foreground` color you can also set its `fontStyle` here as well.  Options are: `italic`, `bold` and `underline` - which can be used in combination with each other too.

As you noticed, with that `Beter C++ Syntax` package, you need to use `@brief` instead of `@desc` in your `cpp` jsdoc-like comments.

Comment: I can only target the scope `comment.block.cpp` which affects the whole comment block not just the `@param` or `@brief`...

Comment: I tested it on a `cpp` file and you are right.  Is there a jsdoc extension for `cpp` files?

Comment: The thing is I don't get the same scopes for a `@param` in `.cpp` file and a `@param` in `.js` file. In `.cpp` files I get the scopes `comment.block.cpp, source.cpp`, in `.js` files I get the scopes `storage.type.class.jsdoc, comment.block.documentation.js, source.js`. What you answered works but only for `.js` files.

Comment: Don't think so for the jsdoc extension for cpp files but I'm looking at it right now

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway @Mark, I found the [Better C++ syntax](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeff-hykin.better-cpp-syntax) package and now I have a proper JSDoc like highlighting :) I'll answer my question